# Not the Same Hash Value a cross serveral nginx instances

Tags: nginx

I Tried to have same result of load balancing across multiple nginx instances based on uri.
I tried some thing like that:

```
 upstream backend {

        hash $request_uri consistent ;
        server <server1>:<port>;
        server <server2>:<port>;

}
```

But i didn't get same server hits from different nginx (same nginx version on same ubuntu version).
So if there is any way to provide a specific seed to this nginx hash function to get same results? Also, how can i print/get the value of this hash from upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx has the same hash value across servers. the problem was that all uri must be the same across all servers.